# Use Bzlmod with registry on local file system?

Tags: bazel, bzlmod

Is it possible to use a Bazel registry with bzlmod that lives on the local filesytem, e.g.:

```
bazel build --enable_bzlmod --registry="file://Users/me/bazel-central-registry" -- //...
```

I downloaded an archive of https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-central-registry and extracted it on my filesystem. When I run the above command pointing at the location where the extracted archive resides I get:

> Error computing the main repository mapping: Error accessing registry file://Users/me/bazel-central-registry: Users

Comment: Try with three slashes after `file:`

Comment: note you can also reference a repo local path using: `--registry=file://%workspace%/registry`

Comment: @JamesSharpe Thee slashes work for me - thanks! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use three slashes i.e.

```
bazel build --enable_bzlmod --registry="file:///Users/me/bazel-central-registry" -- //...
```

Alternatively if you want to have the registry stored within your repository you can use `--registry="file://%workspace%/registry` in order to use a registry stored in a directory called registry at the root of your workspace.